# State Changed But View Not Updating React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-calendars

I am using `'react-native-calendars'` .My Goal is to display dots and then mark multiple dates on users press. Marking dots is a success. I am using `markedDates` object as state variable but when update `markedDates` object to add `'selected':true, 'marked':true` attributes `calendar` does not renders it, I checked the `markedDates` object and everything seemed fine.

below is the code

```
<Calendar style={{width:'100%',height:300}}
                  markingType={'multi-dot'}
                  onDayPress={(day) => {
                   this.handleConfirm2(day);
                  }}
                  markedDates={this.state.markedDates}
            />
```

**handleConfirm2 method below**

```
var calanderObj = this.state.markedDates;
    
      let o = calanderObj ['2021-09-02'];// adding properties to this spec date for testing
      o['selected'] = true;
      o['mark'] = true;

      calanderObj['2021-09-02'] = o;
      
      this.setState({markedDates:calanderObj},function (){
         console.log("after, state changed but calendar not displaing ",this.state.markedDates);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way **(UPDATED)**

```
  /* This will create the clone of the object with a new ref, 
     so whenever the ref is updated, the view reflects */

  const calanderObj = {...this.state.markedDates};
    
  let o = calanderObj ['2021-09-02'];// adding properties to this spec date for testing
  o['selected'] = true;
  o['mark'] = true;

  calanderObj['2021-09-02'] = o;
  
  this.setState({markedDates:calanderObj},function (){
     console.log("after, state changed but calendar not displaing ",this.state.markedDates);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are ( . . . ) dots supposed to mean anything or should I just put my code here? sorry I am new to react and JS

Comment: @usmandroid These are called `Spread operators`. You just try the same as I did and then check. You can read details of it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: I did like this  var calObj = {...this.state.mark};
          ...
          this.setState(...);  it's giving me error on line 2 and 3

Comment: @usmandroid `...` means your existing code goes as it is. I have updated full code please run and check